# How can I define a struct return_dtype which nullable datetimes?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have this code:

```py
df_tables = df_tables.with_columns(
    min_max_commit_time = pl.struct(['schema', 'name']).map_elements(
        lambda r: db.get_mix_max_commit_time_for_table(r['schema'], r['name']),
        return_dtype=pl.Struct({'earliest': pl.Datetime, 'latest': pl.Datetime}),
)
```

`db.get_min_max_commit_time` returns the following type (i.e., dicts where the keys are strings and the values are datetimes or None):

```py
def get_mix_max_commit_time_for_table(self, schema: str, table_name: str) -> dict[str, Union[None, datetime.datetime]]:
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
expected output type 'Struct([Field { name: "earliest", dtype: Datetime(Microseconds, None) }, Field { name: "latest", dtype: Datetime(Microseconds, None) }])', got 'Struct([Field { name: "earliest", dtype: Null }, Field { name: "latest", dtype: Null }])'; set `return_dtype` to the proper datatype
```

How can I allow a nullable datetime in the `return_dtype` struct definition?

Comment: It may be a "bug". https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10398